# AttributeError: DemoOperator instance has no attribute 'optr_jumlah'

Tags: python, python-2.7

In my class DemoOperator, the result is showing AttributeError: DemoOperator instance has no attribute 'optr_jumlah'. please tell me where is the error in coding and what to modify.

```
#program latian

class DemoOperator:
    def __init__(self):
        #input data x dan y
        x = raw_input("Masukkan x : ")
        y = raw_input("Masukkan y : ")

        self.optr_jumlah(int(x), int(y))
        self.optr_kurang(int(x), int(y))
        self.optr_kali(int(x), int(y))
        self.optr_bagi(int(x), int(y))
        self.optr_modulus(int(x), int(y))

        def optr_jumlah(self, a, b):
            a += b
            print "x += y hasilnya ",a

        def optr_kurang(self, a, b):
            a -= b
            print "x -= y hasilnya ",a

        def optr_kali(self, a, b):
            a *= b
            print "x *= y hasilnya ",a

        def optr_bagi(self, a, b):
            a /= b
            print "x /= y hasilnya ",a

        def optr_modulus(self, a, b):
            a %= b
            print "x %= y hasilnya ",a

if __name__ == '__main__':
    aplikasi = DemoOperator()
```

here is some errors that showing from code above:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Kuliah\python\demoOperator.py", line 34, in <module>
    aplikasi = DemoOperator()
  File "E:\Kuliah\python\demoOperator.py", line 7, in __init__
    self.optr_jumlah(int(x), int(y))
AttributeError: DemoOperator instance has no attribute 'optr_jumlah'
```

Thank you for answering my questions.

Comment: `DemoOperator` doesn't have `optr_jumlah` method. You've defined a nested function `optr_jumlah` inside `__init__` method.

Comment: @Alik you should post this as an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @Alik how to define function `optr_jumlah` inside `__init__` method. Sorry im still new in python programming language.

Comment: thank you my problem has been solved. Problem lays on **indentation**.